# Appengine Channel Api presence _ah/channel/connected not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm using the channel API in Java runtime.  The servlet I have mapped to /_ah/channel/connected does not appear to be running.  I am creating a channel, passing the token, and opening it on the server.  This works fine.  I do see the call to /_ah/channel/connected in my log, however no log messages appear and the code does not appear to be running.  Below is my code and web.xml

ChannelConnectedServlet.java:

```
public class ChannelConnectedServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ChannelConnectedServlet.class
          .getName());  

    private void process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException { 
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"test");
        //do stuff here
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                   throws IOException, ServletException {        
       logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Channel connected!");
       process(req, resp);
     }
}
```

web.xml:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ChannelConnected</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/_ah/channel/connected</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> 

 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>ChannelConnected</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.myapp.server.channel.ChannelConnectedServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
```

The same behavior happens with the disconnect request.  HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entry in web.xml should have included "/" at the end of the url, such as:

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>ChannelConnected</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/_ah/channel/connected/</url-pattern>
```

Works now.